# ¿Como agrego un REGEX en vue?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, vue.js

estoy empezando a usar el framework de vue y pues quisiera pedir una ayuda, quiero hacer un zipcode con vue, pero no sé donde pondría el regex, más bien no sé como ponerlo. Acá les dejo lo que tengo.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <label>Zip code: </label>
    <input class="form-control" v-model="message" type="number" id="zip" :class="color" >

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      message: '12345'
    }
  },

  methods: {
    revision(){
      /*Segun yo acá iría el REGEX*/ 
    }
  }, 
  computed:{
    color(){
      return this.message.length === 5 ? 'border-success' : 'border-danger'
    }
  }
};

</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si. podes ponerlo a ahi. quien va a ejecutar ese metodo? vue no es mas que un framework de vista, pero la validacion sigue siendo como en cualquier pagina con js.